# Apache permission problem in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

i am new to ubuntu , i have install ubuntu 12.04 install in my system i have install localhost(lamp) in my system . i was trying to import a data base with more size so 
dor that i need to change the php.ini file which was there in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

but php.ini file was in read onely mode so i change the permission of apache2 folder like

```
      chmod -R 777 apache2
```

and now i am not able to use php myadmin , can any 1 tell me what to do ??????????????

Comment: i am getting this message when use my phpmyadmin                                                    Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!

Comment: hi friends i solved this by changing the permission of config.inc.php file (under phpmyadmin folder in etc ) to 755 it worked now i am able to use php myadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stop Apache using `sudo service apache stop`. Giving recursive 777 privileges is not recommended unless there is an absolute need.

Presuming that you issued that `chmod` command for the `/etc/php5/apache2` directory, you can reset the permissions to the default. Here's the contents of the same directory on my system which is configured as a LAMP server:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Apr  4  2012 conf.d -> ../conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67479 Apr  9  2013 php.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68428 Jun 13  2012 php.ini.ucf-dist
```

You would need to `chmod` the `php.ini` and `php.ini.ucf.dist` files with

```
sudo chmod 644 filename
```

The error you're getting from phpMyAdmin is for it's own configuration file - `config.inc.php` found at the root level of your phpMyAdmin installation. Managing this file is explained in the [phpMyAdmin Wiki here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install).

To edit the `php.ini` file you will need to invoke `sudo` when using your CLI text editor like `vi` or `pico`, such as `sudo pico /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

It complains about the permissions set on the folder. With your command you gave everyone full write(!) and read permissions to every file in this folder and its sub-folders.

Run the following commands to set the permissions back:

```
sudo chmod a-x -R /etc/php5/apache2/
sudo chmod a-w -R /etc/php5/apache2/
sudo chmod 755 /etc/php5/apache2/
sudo chmod 644 /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sudo chmod 644 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/*
```

**A small note:**
Never use `chmod -R` until you exactly know what you are doing. `chmod -R` sets permissions recursively to every file and folder under the given path. You can destroy your entire system.